# 'Or' Operator in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Does it exist an OR operator in RoR ? I want or archieve something like this :

```
Model.where('cat_id' => 5 OR 'color' => 'grey').all
```

I think I must use `find_by_sql`nop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider looking at the [MetaWhere gem](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/). It supports compound conditions with syntax like this:

```
Article.where(:title.matches % 'Hello%' | :title.matches % 'Goodbye%')
```

It has a lot more to it than just that but it is a really great gem to augment Arel.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is the way:

```
Model.where('cat_id=? OR color=?', 5, 'grey')
```